# gazebo ackermann car simulation

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently planning to set up a gazebo simulation for an ackermann steering vehicle (mainly with the intention to work on non-holonomic path-planning). Does anyone know if there are some urdf descriptions for such a car available somewhere?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10265/gazebo-ackermann-car-simulation/) by [uschwes](https://answers.ros.org/users/694/uschwes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a URDF file for a Traxxas E-Maxx four-wheel-drive RC truck, along with Gazebo plug-ins to simulate shock absorbers, the steering servo, and the ESC. I'll put these items in a package and publish them.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uschwes](https://answers.ros.org/users/694/uschwes/) on 2011-06-16**:
Thanks for your answers! I digged in a bit deeper into the topic (still quite new to ROS) with the help of the ackermann example urdf file and would now have to start writing the controller plugin. But the model in the thread posted by Bemfica is VERY simple and I'm aiming for an a bit more sophisticated model. So let me know when and under which name you'll gonna publish your items, I'd really appreciate getting some more input on how to model all this (shock absorbers, maybe tire characteristics, etc.)

Thanks!

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) on 2012-10-26**:
Hey Jim,

Have you ever gotten around to publishing a package for your RC truck? I was trying to search for it but couldn't find it.

Thanks,
Thomas

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on 2012-11-26**:
Yes, see http://wiki.ros.org/ackermann_vehicle.

**Comment by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on 2016-08-16**:
Hey Jim
I'm working on a model of an ackermann steering vehicle and would like to look into your files to get an idea how to implement a controller for the ackermann steering. Unfortunately your package doesn't exist anymore. Would it be possible to upload your package again?
Thanks in advance
Gleb

**Comment by [H_Gottlieb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29061/h_gottlieb/) on 2017-01-15**:
Hey Jim. How would you use your package with a different model? (for example the polaris ranger ev that is in the gazebo database)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe take a look at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/459/how-can-i-simulate-ackermann-steering-in-gazebo) question.

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2